# javascript for loop: issues

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

i came across this problem: Write a program that uses console.log to print all the numbers from 1 to 100, with two exceptions. For numbers divisible by 3, print “Fizz” instead of the number, and for numbers divisible by 5 (and not 3), print “Buzz” instead. When you have that working, modify your program to print “FizzBuzz” for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5 (and still print “Fizz” or “Buzz” for numbers divisible by only one of those).

and i tried solving it with the code below:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if(i % 3 ===0) {
        console.log("fizz");
    } else if ( i % 5 === 0 ) {
        console.log("buzz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("fizzbuzz");
    } 
    console.log(i);
}
```

please can anyone tell me what i did wrong because i am not getting result

Comment: The gist of FizzBuzz problem is that while the first 2 conditions are mutually exclusive, the 3rd one is not.  So the order of your `if`s matter.

Comment: Also, you said you need to print FizzBuzz for numbers that are divisible by both 3 and 5, but your if condition will evaluate to true if the number is divisible by 3 *or* 5, so you should change that last if to: `if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0)`, but first change the order of the if statements like PM 77-1 said

Answer (score 1):

In your condition, `i = 15` should be returned `fizzbuzz` but it returns `fizz` because 15 can be divided by 3 and 5 so you first condition `i % 3 === 0` getting `true` so it returned `fizz`. if your first condition is `i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0` then `i = 15` should be return `fizzbuzz`.

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("fizzbuzz");
    } else if(i % 3 ===0) {
        console.log("fizz");
    } else if ( i % 5 === 0 ) {
        console.log("buzz");
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```